# HttpURLConnection, HttpClient and HttpPost request not working with POST request in Android

Tags: android, http-post, response, httpurlconnection

I have tried many different ways to get http response but always I am getting message null. I have tried using Advance Rest Client tool that comes with chrome. In that i get the response with success. I dnt know where i am doing wrong.

```
try {

        String urlParameters = "id=userid&password=password&device=android";

        URL url = new URL("my url");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(urlParameters.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();

        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            resultstring = convertinputStreamToString(in);
            Log.d("Result String-------->", resultstring);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have attached screenshot where i get result: success
But in above code I get result: failure

[image]

I have also tried code using HttpClient and HttpPost. But this also doent work

```
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "my url");

        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "userid"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device", "android"));

        // httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity se = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
        se.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        httpPost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(
                "http.protocol.expect-continue", false);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

        String responseAsText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("Result String-------->", responseAsText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please help me out. I have tried almost everything.

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpClient localHttpClient = this.app2.getHttpClient();
  HttpPost localHttpPost = new HttpPost("yourURL.com");
  localHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(myArrayList));
  InputStream localInputStream = localHttpClient.execute(localHttpPost).getEntity().getContent();
```

Try something like this. 
You must read the response as an input stream and then do your work after the result is returned.

also, be sure to check the server as it may not be returning the response as expected.